# azure rest api for azure container apps

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps

is there an api or azure golang sdk for "Azure Container Apps" service ?, this is still in preview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/?ocid=AID3042118

There is no listing of this in the Azure Rest API portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Thanks -Nen.

Comment: The service is still in preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the Azure Container Apps is still in preview, there is no REST API for this service as of now**

Answer (score 1):

The REST API reference is now available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerapps/